# I want to JavaScript variable get as a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

My question:
I need a JavaScript variable to pass to a PHP variable. I have done this, but the passed PHP variable does not support input text field `value=""` attribute. How can I fix this problem?

```
<input type="number" onchange="myFunction()" >
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = 4;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Working `$p`:

```
<?php 
    $p ='<p id="demo"></p>';
    echo $p;   
?>
```

But, `$p` variable does not work within `value=''`

```
<input type='text' name='p3' value='<?= $p ?>'>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're missing some information from your question. You have a JS script that sets the `innerHTML` for a PHP rendered element with the `id` of "demo". But then you show us an `input`, but nothing else. Where is `$p` being set for the `input` element?

Comment: i updated my question . check now

Comment: That input isn't the same as what you provided. Do you have a PHP function somewhere? As of right now, you are only using an input to run a JS function. You could put a PHP rendered value into the `script`, but if you need to get a dynamic value from PHP using JS, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: can you give me ajax reference for solve my problem

Comment: i need to javascript variable pass to  php variable  and after that php variable add to text field like as value="<?php echo $p ?> "

Comment: example:- <input type='text' name='p3' value='<?= $p ?>'>

Comment: Why do you need to pass a Javascript variable to PHP? This now seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: that is short part of my code

Comment: We need more code to know what you want, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: JavaScript can not update PHP. That requires you to send an http request back to the server for PHP to interact with a value. You need to learn about the page lifecycle to understand how PHP interacts with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server language so it means that it loads the values before the page is rendered. Javascript renders and handles everything after the page is loaded by PHP.

For this you need to create an alternate php file that receives that value and the give it back to your input.

Comment: can you explain more. how fix my erro

Comment: if you explain me what exactly u want I can give u a code example for

Comment: i need to javascript variable pass to php variable and after that php variable add to text field like as value="<?php echo $p ?>

Comment: example:- <input type='text' name='p3' value='<?= $p ?>'>

Comment: You can't use PHP for that. Use JavaScript.

Comment: as @NikolaStojiljković say you cannot do that directly with PHP, you have to do it by javascript, instead of <?php echo $p ?>, you just set the value as <input type='text' name='p3' id='p3' value='' /> and in your function you do something lik  document.getElementById("p3").value = x;